# I can't update mysql database using django？

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
class Person(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
                    ('S', 'Small'),
                    ('M', 'Medium'),
                    ('L', 'Large'),
                    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

this is the new code I want use.However, it raise the error

### UnKnown column 'first_name' in person

first_name is the previous variable I  used in class Person.
My django verson is 1.10 and I have tried drop the schema and restart the server.

Comment: Have you already run your migrations?

Comment: which db are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create the database schema using the command(s):

#### For Django 1.9 or Greater

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
python  manage.py migrate
```

#### For Django 1.8 and Earlier

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

**NOTE:** Also, in case you change your model fields you'd need to update the schema which for Django 1.9+ can be done using the same commands `makemigrations` and after that `migrate`.

For more information, please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/).